# Suggestions for Shavuot all-night learning session

Tags: torah-study, shavuos

Besides Meguilat Rut and the laws pertaining to Yom Tov in general, is there anything Lail Shavuot is specifically considered a good time to learn about, Torah-wise?

Comment: No specific source for this, but, a few rabbanim have told me that items related to *Safrut* are appropriate, as the Torah was given on Shavuot. So something like Masechet Sofrim or Kesset Hasofer would be appropriate.

Comment: As it stands this almost sounds too broad/primarily opinion-based. Maybe you should edit it to read “what do traditional sources encourage one to learn on Shavuos night” or something to that effect?

Comment: I think "specifically considered" is assumed to mean "by traditional sources" rather than "by that guy Yonathan who used to date Sheila from down the Shore and davened at shul with us one time", @DonielF, but if it's a real eyesore I have no problem editing

Comment: My rav gives a shiur on the sefer mitzvos of the Rambam the entire night.

Comment: I did say “almost” and I personally think it’s fine as it is. I was just pointing out that the wording lends to that interpretation.

Comment: To be honest @DonielF I had no idea about the tikkun tradition and so was looking to cast as broad a net as possible.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7285/which-passages-comprise-the-classic-tikkun-leil-shavuot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Pri Eitz Chaim](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%A5_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%92_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%90) writes:

> והנה מה שראוי לקרות בליל שבועות, כדי להמשיך הכתר הנ"ל, הוא זה, שתקרא ג' פסוקים ראשונים, וג' אחרונים, מכל סדר וסדר, ואם נזדמן לו פרשה פתוחה מד' או ה' פסוקים, בין בתחלת הפרשה בין בסוף הפרשה, צריך לקרותה. בפרשת בראשית עד לעשות, סוף פרשת ויכולו. וכן מכל נביא ונביא, וכן של כתובים, וכבר נדפס:
>
> (נ"א מע"ח - צריך לקרות דניאל קודם דברי הימים, ואחר כל הסדר נוהגים החברים לקרות אדרא רבא, מן זמן הרב רבי אפרים ז"ל. אמנם הכתובים של מגלת איכה יקרא בלחש, כי הוא י"ט. ותקרא הפטרה דיום א' דשבועות, ביחזקאל, ובחבקוק הפטורה דיום ב', ותכוין בסיום כל ספר, בהשמות היוצאין מס"ת הספרים כ"ד, שהם נגד כ"ד תכשיטי כלה, הנזכר בימי אלול, מכתב יד מורי זלה"ה, והניקוד אות א' בקיבוץ, ואות אחרונה בקמץ, והם בסוד דע"ק וכ"ע עתיקא, והם התדפ עב וכו', ה'ד'ע' בשורוק, ת' פ' ב' בקמץ, ואיני יודע מנין לו. ומה שאני עיינתי וחקרתי הוא, כי אלו השמות יוצאין מר"ת ומס"ת של תיבה שנייה של פסוק אחרון מכל ספר וספר. (מתלמידי אר"י ז"ל, כתבו כ"ד צרופים אחרים, כגון בו, ב' בשורוק ו' בקמץ, היוצא מתיבה הסמוכה לאחרונה שבסוף הספר, כגון בארון. בן, ב' בשורוק בקמץ, וכן בספר ב' בכל מסעיהם בל וכו', ב' בשורוק ל' בקמץ) מהרי"ס, שהם טובים להצלחה ולזכירה, ומסוגלים מאוד לכוין בהם) ע"כ:
>
> What should a person learn that night? The first three verses of every portion, and if he if there's a portion that's 4 or 5 verses long, one should read it. One should also read [the first Aliyah of] Bereishis, so too one should read from every [book] in Tanach. This [order]  has already been printed.
>
> One should read Daniel before Divrei Hayamim, and after that one should read the Idra Rabbah [(a part of the Zohar)]. Eicha one should read quietly, as it's a Yom Tov. One should also read the Haftorah of both days of Shavuos.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the selections from Tanach and the Idra Rabbah mentioned in [Shmuel Brin's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92349/14850), the Ashkenazi Tikkun Leil Shavu'ot traditionally also includes selections from:

- Mishnayot (the first and last *mishnah* of each *masechet*)
- Sefer Yetzirah (the beginning and end)
- Zohar (from Parashat Emor discussing *sefirat ha'omer* and Shavuot)
- A list of all 613 *mitzvot* (based on Rambam's count)

Of course, not everyone says all of these. See discussions in [Nit'ei Gavriel, Hilchot Shavu'ot](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46443&st=&pgnum=110&hilite=) Chapter 15, paras. 1, 2, 9 and footnotes thereon for details.